# What is the meaning of the sentence, "It was just the genius of Gandhi to notice faultless occasions"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I'm translating an article by Paul Goodman written in 1961 about pacifist films. I can't fully understand the meaning of the sentence, **"It was just the genius of Gandhi to notice faultless occasions."**

The context of the phrase,

> The charismatic excitement that gives courage and solidarity must emerge in each concrete occasion of pacifist action, and it will emerge, if it is really a man’s own occasion. We are in the tradition of bearing witness. It was just the genius of Gandhi to notice faultless occasions.

And what is the tradition of bearing witness?

Comment: The genius of Gandhi was to notice (_consisted in his noticing_) faultless occasions.

Comment: It's a somewhat "affected" use of ***occasion*** in the full OED's sense 10a - *Something that a person needs to do; necessary business; a matter, a piece of business, a business engagement. Chiefly in plural: affairs, business.* I didn't know that sense until I just searched the OED for an example citation including the words **his own occasion** (and I won't go out of my way to remember it! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that at least part of the point of the sentence is that many people notice occasions on which things go wrong, but Gandhi  was unusual in that he noticed occasions on which things when exactly as planned, so that no fuss or problem resulted.

I disagree with the [comment by FumbleFingers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/324700/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-sentence-it-was-just-the-genius-of-gandhi-to-notice#comment611753_324700), I think this is the more usual sense of "occasion" meaning "event".

As to "*bearing witness*", that term comes from a religious, largely Christian, tradition. Those who see and remember some event, particularly a significant one, and later describe it to others, are said to be bearing witness to it.